# ReactJs cannot read property 'map' of undefined despite the initial state is set?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using Redux inside my app.
I've set initial state inside the reducer but apparently something is not correct, as I'm getting the following error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Here's the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  machines: [
    {
    id: "1",
    identifier: "My Machine 1",
    location: "My Location 1"
    }
  ]
};


export default function machines(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And here's the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Machines extends Component {

  createMachinesList() {
    return this.props.machines.map((machine) => {
      return (
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td key={machine.id}>{machine.identifier}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td key={machine.id}>{machine.location}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            Equipment
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            {this.createMachinesList()}
            <button>edit</button><button>delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    equipment: state.machines,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Machines);
```

here's reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import machines from "./machines";


const allReducers = combineReducers({
  machines,
})

export default allReducers;
```

And inside index.js

```
let store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
          return <Route to={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
        })}
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**EDIT:
I've replaced "equipment" with "machines" inside mapStatetoProp as suggested below. I now get a different error: 
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.machines.map is not a function**

What is it that I need to change? I'm stuck on this.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can we see your store and reducer config? One of the answers below can solve your problem but just to be sure, providing that info would be good.

Comment: @devserkan Edited my question to add the info. I've now changed the name of equipment to machines, but I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.machines.map is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming Redux states can be confusing if you don't choose specific, good ones :)
You have a global state which is `state`. You have a reducer there and holds a state which is an object, and it has a property named `machines`.

You open this state with your `combineReducers` function as `machines` again. Now you have something like that.

- `state`: global state
- `state.machines`: machines state in your global state which you are initializing with your reducer.
- `state.machines.machines`: This is the object property which holds your array.

This is confusing :) But this is not enough confusing I believe since you used your `mapStateToProps` function like that in your first version:

```
return {
    equipment: state.machines,
}
```

What do you do here? You open your `state.machines` state to your component as `equipment`. Then, if you want to reach your `machines` property here you should use `this.props.equipment.machines`. So, if you used @borube's advise you would solve your problem. This is why I upvoted his/her answer but I want to be sure and asked for your other configuration.

Now, you changed `mapStateToProps` like that:

```
return {
  machines: state.machines,
}
```

What you have now is: `state.machines.machines`. You should use `this.props.machines.machines`.

Again, choosing better names could be useful :)

**Update after comments**

Yeah, it is funny. I also laughed to myself when I did the same mistake a while ago when learning Redux :) `state.someState.someState.foo.bar` Oh god! Then I tried to think better names.

This is totally up to you. What is your reducer defining? Think a good, generic name (of course generic for this reducer state) then use properties in this state.

I don't know your final desire here but you used `equipment` once, then maybe state name can be `equipments` which is plural? Then you will have a state and a reducer like that in the future?

```
const initialState = {
  machines: [
    {
    id: "1",
    identifier: "My Machine 1",
    location: "My Location 1"
    }
  ],
  cars: [],
  otherEquipments: [],
};


export default function equipments(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now, when you use this state you will reach each equipment with: `this.props.equipments.machines`, `this.props.equipments.cars`, etc.

In order to use `state.machines` your state should be something like that:

```
const initialState = [
    {
        id: "1",
        identifier: "My Machine 1",
        location: "My Location 1"
    }
];
```

and you will reach this item as `this.props.machines[0]` or map through to get all the items for this array. If you will keep just machines here then you can go for this way maybe. But, if there will be other pieces of equipment, making it an object probably is better.

Comment: You made me want to laugh and hide under the table at the same time :) Thank you for explaining. Can you please point me in the right direction with choosing better names? How can I avoid the state.machines.machines and just have state.machines?

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated my answer. We all laugh to ourselves time to time :)

Comment: Got it! I can't thank you enough. I would double-accept your answer if that was possible :)

Answer (score 3):

You mapped your reducer 'machines' to a prop called equipment. you need to do this.props.equipment.machines.map

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the equipment to `machines` in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Done. I now get the error: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.machines.map is not a function. Any clues? Thank you.